# MySQL / PHP - User filter variable to return all values

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks in advance for checking out this question.

I have a series of HTML select elements where a user can define what data they want returning from the MySQL database. Each of the choices are stored in a variable. Some of the options enable the user to choose "No Preference" in which case the sql statement needs to accept a variable allowing it to return all the fields of that specific column.

I am using PHP for reference.

Does this exist or is it a poor code set up ? currently the SQL statement is accepting the variables in this format

```
AND `operationalTier1`='$userOps'
AND `modelName`='$userEndpoint'
AND `status`='$userStatus'
AND `sourceName`='$userSource'
AND `metSLA`='$userSLA'
```

The Select for the user to choose from is in this format

```
 <h3>Data Filters</h3>
            <p>Case Created</p>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <p>Ops Tier 1</p>
            <select name="ops_1_select">
                <option>No Preference</option>
                <option>Add/Create</option>
                <option>Delete/Remove</option>
                <option>Fix</option>
                <option>Inform</option>
            </select>
```

Setting the option to a variable

```
 if ($_POST['ops_1_select'] = "No Preference")
            {
                $userOps= XXXX
            } else
            {
                $userOps= $_POST['ops_1_select'];
            }
```

So If the user selects "No preference" I need the variable to store something that will return all of the ops tiers from the db which would replace XXXX

Comment: Can you post the code you've written already?

Comment: It's mixed in with a lot of other elements but I will try and bring out the key parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statement you should be using an equality operator (==) and not an assignment operator (=). That if statement will always result to true and it will set the value of the $_POST key you've selected. Change `if ($_POST['ops_1_select'] = "No Preference")` to `if ($_POST['ops_1_select'] == "No Preference")`

Before:

```
if ($_POST['ops_1_select'] = "No Preference")
            {
                $userOps= XXXX
            } else
            {
                $userOps= $_POST['ops_1_select'];
            }
```

After:

```
if ($_POST['ops_1_select'] == "No Preference") {
    $userOps = "XXXX";
} else {
    $userOps = $_POST['ops_1_select'];
}
```

You can find some more information [here](http://sourcedaddy.com/php/differentiate-equal-signs.html)

---

So, based on your comments on this answer I'll share a little more code I think might help:

```
$fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');
$query = 'text'; // should be everything up until your first WHERE

for ($fields as $key => $val) {
     if ($_POST[$val] == 'No Preference') {
         // IS NOT NULL will return true as long as the field is set
         $and = $val . ' IS NOT NULL';
     } else {
         $and = $val . ' = "' . $_POST[$val] . '"';
     }
     $query = $query . $and . ' AND ';
}

// Remove the trailing AND from $query, add anything else you need, run query
```

Some more notes, VALIDATE YOUR INPUT DATA! If you aren't using PDO/mysqli or another database abstraction engine, now is the time to start. As is this code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that but do you know what value I can pass to just return all values in the instance of a "No preference being selected"

Comment: Why would you want to pass all values? After you've extracted the $_POST data you should be able make another if statement something like `if ($userOps == "XXXX") { //run query that doesnt care about their preference } else { //run query that does care about $userOps }`

Comment: Given that there are multiple user selects to filter upon this would mean listing out off of the possibilities and combinations of filtering

Comment: There are pretty elegant ways it can be done using prepared statements and a database abstraction engine like PDO. How many conditions do you have?

Comment: There are 9 selections for the user

Comment: I added a little more code to my answer, see if that helps a little.

Comment: This looks like it might work but its way above my level, I only started coding a couple of days ago

Answer (score 0):

I would use `LIKE` insted of `=` and add a `%`.

```
AND `operationalTier1` LIKE '$userOps'
```

And:

```
$userOps= '%';
```

Or you can remove the condition `AND operationalTier1='$userOps'` from your sql statement when `No Preference` is set.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, the issue with this is that there are approximately 8 user selects so how would I determine if they have or haven't selected the option without creating hundreds of sql statements for each possible combination

Comment: You can also just add `value="%"` to the select option. to remove the if statements. But I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: It's hard to explain I would have to show you the code but its hundreds of lines long in total